# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restful'

Tags: docker, flask, flask-restful

I've been trying this for awhile now with no luck. Making a basic api but running into some trouble with the flask_restful module. This is my code:

```
import markdown
import os
import shelve
from flask import Flask, g
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse

app = Flask(__name)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    with open(os.path.dirname(app.root_path) + 
            '/README.md', 'r') as markdown_file:
        content = markdown_file.read()
        return markdown.markdown(content)
```

This is my requirements.txt:

```
docker==3.4.1
docker-compose==1.22.0
docker-pycreds==0.3.0
dockerpty==0.4.1
docopt==0.6.2
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.6
requests==2.18.4
urllib3==1.22
websocket-client==0.48.0
```

This is what I get as an error when running docker-compose up:

```
Starting python-rest_device-registry_1 ... done
Attaching to python-rest_device-registry_1
device-registry_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
device-registry_1  |   File "./run.py", line 1, in <module>
device-registry_1  |     from device_registry import app
device-registry_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/device_registry/__init__.py", line 6, 
in <module>
device-registry_1  |     from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
device-registry_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restful'
python-rest_device-registry_1 exited with code 1
```

My docker file is this:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./run.py" ]
```

What am I doing wrong here? I pip installed Flask and flask_restful but I'm lost for word on what's going on.

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: Ok, just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like you are using `flask_restful` in the code you are showing here. You are just importing it. It might be possible that you started out with just some flask code, which imports ok, then added flask-restful to your requirements file but docker in unaware of it and it has a cached version of that part of the container.

Try to decouple your problem, start by running your python sample outside docker, in a plain old virtualenv and make sure that starts. Then mess look into how docker is installing or not your newly added requirements.

Comment: Perfect! It worked. So imported markdown since it wasn't installed yet, then did docker-compose build, and now everything works. Thank you. After testing it outside of docker, I figured out the problem.